# Is there a general way to determine the number of indices used in a numpy indexing expression?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-indexing

Many different things can be used as indexers in `numpy`, in my case most commonly lists of integers and Boolean expressions, but slices etc are also on the table.
Now I have a function that takes as an argument an indexing expression and uses corresponding elements of a precomputed array.
As a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
def f(indexer):
    return f.M[:,indexer]
f.M = np.repeat([[1,2,3,4,5]],3,axis=0)
# now I can call f with different indexing expressions
f([1,4])
f(slice(0,None,2))
f([True, False, True, False, False])
```

Now I'd like to work out the shape of `f(indexer)` *before* actually doing the indexing (I need that to construct some auxiliary arrays).
For a list, it's clearly `(3, len(indexer))` and for a Boolean indexing expression it's `(3, np.nonzero(indexer))`, for a slice I wouldn't even know, but is there a (simple, fast, Pythonic, general) way to get me the size of `f.M[:,indexer]` *independently* of what sort of indexing expression I use? And if it's not a universal one, then maybe at least one that works for Boolean expressions and lists?

Comment: Hang on. I answered this exact question in the general case a couple of months ago

Comment: Ah yes, you did indeed! Google didn't turn up that one for me though, only looking through your recent answers did. I flagged mine as a duplicate, so the next Google search has a better chance of leading to the original question, which was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852754

Comment: Heh. I couldn't find it myself. Nice work!

Comment: To make it explicit, you would call `estimate_size(f.M.shape, (slice(None), indexer))`

Comment: To reliably do this I'd stick with actually doing the indexing.  If the `indexer` is a `slice`, you can use `index.stop` and `index.start` to calculate the length - except if the `index.step` isn't `None`.  And any of these can `None`, which need special handling, including knowing the `shape` of `M`.  Also slices may "go off' the end.  Way too many special cases to handle.  Plus if it is a slice, the `M[:,indexer]` will be a view, which is computationally fast.

Comment: Something that may be both fast and reliable, is to construct a dummy array that has 0 rows.  `np.zeros((0,M.shape[1]))[:,indices].shape[1]`.  This should produce the same change in dim 1 shape as `M[:,indices]`, but without any of the copying expense.